# Rails : Can't connect to MySQL se rver on 'localhost' (10061) (Mysql::Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a strange problem. When I try ro make `rails s` , it says me :

```
C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/conne
ction_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:411:in `real_connect': Can't connect to MySQL se
rver on '127.0.0.0' (10060) (Mysql::Error)
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:411:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:131:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:38:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:38:in `mysql_connection'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in `new_connection'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in `checkout_new_con
nection'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in `block (2 levels)
 in checkout'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `loop'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `block in checkou
t'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:233:in `checkout'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `block in connecti
on'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connect
ion'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:170:in `retriev
e_connection'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:144:in `connect
ion'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active
_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/activ
e_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__319095901__prepare__837475246__callbacks'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/activ
e_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/activ
e_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/activ
e_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_d
ispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_d
ispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/appl
ication/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/init
ializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/appl
ication.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rail
tie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Ruby/acturevue/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/activ
e_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/acturevue/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.r
b:51:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.r
b:51:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby/acturevue/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby/acturevue/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.r
b:40:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.r
b:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb
:200:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comm
ands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb
:301:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb
:252:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comm
ands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comm
ands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comm
ands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comm
ands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

What I can't understand, is that yesterday, everything worked well ! This morning, Windows updated, so maybe there's a link, no ?

Also, I can't access to `localhost:3000` but I can connect to the login page of PhpMyAdmin (it refuses me the connexion after writing my login/password ) with : `localhost:81`

I found some solutions before writting this post, but no one worked for me !

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Here's my db.yml :

```
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: acturevue_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password
  host: localhost
```

**UPDATE**
Gemfile to see if a gem could be the problem :

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql'



# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'


gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem "bootstrap-sass", ">= 2.1.0.0"

gem "rolify", ">= 3.2.0"
gem "simple_form", ">= 2.0.3"
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the sockect for mysql

```
development:
 adapter: mysql
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 database: acturevue_development
 pool: 5
 username: root
 password: password
 host: localhost
 socket: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock //this path must point to your mysql socket
```

p.s. you need to specify this option both under Linux and Windows, not entirely sure under Mac OS.

Comment: I can't find any mysql.sock ... I've installed Ruby with BitnamiRubystack. Why was it working yesterday without socket, and yesterday no ?

Comment: You are running it under Windows, right? I'm not exactly sure, but check if you have installed any gems which might conflict or maybe a spelling mistake? As @Lichtamberg suggested check if your MySQL is working. What do you use for that .. xampp or everything comes with BitnamiRubystack ?

Comment: Everything comes with BitnamyRubystack. I'll edit my first post with my gemfile. But, again, everything worked well yesterday, so I don't think a gem could be the problem. I think it's the Windows 7 update that is the reason. Also, when I try `mysql connect ` it says me : `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`

Comment: Do you think it could hep to re-install Bitnamy Rubystack ?

Comment: Not really sure. Try to restore your machine before the update and see if that helps. If that doesn't help, back up your work and reinstall the Bitnamy Rubystack. The general problem I had running rails under windows 7 is that rails behaves better under Linuxwise system, where under windows some of the gems gave me weird errors specific for windows only. So I would recommend you not to use windows.

Comment: So, I re-installed Bitnami Rubystack, uninstalled the windows updates, and nothing happens. I'm going to install linux as you recommanded.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

In gem file

> gem 'mysql', '2.8.1'

In database.yml

development:

```
adapter: mysql
 encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: acturevue_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
 password: password
  host: 127.0.0.0
```

Hope it will work for you :)